# Is Dogville inspired from Hitchcock's Rear Window?

Tags: analysis, rear-window, dogville

Watching these 2 movies I found similarities between them. The visual city in [**Dogville**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0276919/) reminds me of [**Rear Window**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047396/), where the hero is watching to everything from his window.

Is this a case of an homage or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In a lot of ways, [Rope (1948)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040746/) has inspired a number of feature films. Two that come to mind are Rear Window (1954) and Murder by Numbers (2002).
>
> [Rope](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040746/) is always a film this writer will suggest to people at the end of the day. In many ways Rope represents a time period where Hitchcock was trying to try something new. After all, the film is an adaptation from a stage play. By using long takes, he gave the feeling of a play on screen. This of course has been done other ways by this point in time, think of 2003's Dogville. By using long takes and keeping more of a set that did not appear to be an on stage production, Hitchcock dared to be different. In many ways, this is part of the reason this writer admires the man ever so much. Hitchcock was never afraid to be different.

So reading the [article](http://www.examiner.com/movie-in-atlanta/right-and-wrong-were-invented-for-the-ordinary-average-man-rope-film-review-review) I think Dogville and Rear Window are not directly related, but they have *Rope* movie as a common factor. You might read this [article](http://www.themovingarts.com/lars-von-triers-dogville-and-the-dogme-legacy/) too, that explains pretty much the similarities.