# Is the introduction of Snake Eyes a reference to Rope?

Tags: analysis, film-techniques, reference, rope, snake-eyes

While I guess it isn't a big secret that *Alfred Hitchcock* has always been a huge inspiration for *Brian De Palma*, one possible connection between both of them has only occurred to me recently. The introduction of *De Palma*'s [*Snake Eyes*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120832/) is famous for being shot continuously without any *visible* cuts. Another movie that famously exhibits this property is *Hitchcock*'s [*Rope*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040746/) (as also discussed in [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/15916/49)). Add to this that the story of *Snake Eyes* unfolds in real-time, which is more or less the case for *Rope*, too.

Now is there any information (or at least further indication from the respective movies) **if the introduction of *Snake Eyes* is a direct reference to *Rope*** or am I just making things up here?

Comment: Nope you're not making things up atleast this guy thinks so http://www.deseretnews.com/article/700002065/Snake-Eyes.html?pg=all

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, let me see if i could dig around something else.

Comment: The biggest movie reference in snake eyes is the 1950 Japanese movie Rashomon by Kurosawa. Everyone has a story to tell and none are the complete truth. De palma does an excellent job of extending the technique with the pov camera. He also does a excellent job when break with it to give us a plot twist that needs no dialogue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, Brian De Palma is a known fan of Alfred Hitchcock ([1](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1694248/brian-de-palma-afred-hitchcock-biopic.jhtml)) ([2](http://collider.com/brian-de-palma-passion-untouchables-prequel-capone-rising/)).

In [this interview](http://www.filmscouts.com/scripts/interview.cfm?File=bri-dep) he explains:

> *We didn't set out to do a "[Brian De Palma Signature SteadiCam Shot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_De_Palma#Camera_shots)".*
>
> ***I wanted to show the whole universe that the Nick Cage character was in. I wanted to show HIS world, I wanted to show it really fast, and I wanted to show it whole**, in an exciting venue: with that particular fight night, and the money stuff before the fight and the murder during the fight and the aftermath of the fight AND of the murder, he has a lot of problems to solve, and they're all tied up, in a way.*

[...]

> ***I wanted the movie to start with a long, incredibly long shot.** I wanted it to start on the boardwalk and end on the boardwalk. With a very long shot.*

[...]

> ***It's actually four SteadiCam shots.** They don't make twenty-minute camera magazines, so we had to use four or five of them. Basically it's like three or four five-minute shots.*
>
> ***You're not supposed to see the seams, but they're there. The cut is there. I faked it the same way Hitchcock faked his real-time no-cuts thing in "Rope".***

Comment: P.S.: As Brian De Palma mentions in the interview, his [Bonfire of the Vanities](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099165/) also [starts with a long shot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luui7KGzciY).

Comment: My favorite example of stealing from other movies, [The Player](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0epB5Z6ijpk), is also a likely influence as it sets up the protagonist's whole world.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I guess what we're supposed to take from it is that (1) While it wasn't done as a direct reference to *Rope* on purpose, the way it was achieved was probably directly influenced by it and (2) that long continuous takes are a common technique employed by *De Palma* (even if maybe not always as extensively as in this scene).