# What is the longest, single take, tracking shot in cinema/TV?

Tags: film-techniques, cinema-history

In episode four of True Detective, there was a 6-minute long, single take, tracking shot sequence.

What is the longest, scripted, **single take** (no cuts) sequence in movies / television?

I am not considering live (sketch comedy, reality television, improv, talk shows, etc.) or presentation-style (documentaries, how-to shows, etc.) takes.

Answers are not restricted to any particular recording media (film, digital, etc.), just the length of the single take and that the content be of intent.  For example, the True Detective sequence was a 6-minute long action sequence with no cuts made as the camera followed the complex, scripted sequence with no cheats or trickery involved.

Comment: Not really a tracking shot, but the extended take in Old Boy was around four minutes long. Definitely not a record, but it deserves mention since it was a fighting scene.

Comment: All the movies in the Before {Sunrise, Sunset, Midnight}-trilogy have long takes, and I believe at least one clocks in at around 13 minutes ([source](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/film/starsandstories/10131966/Before-Midnight-the-lovers-return.html))

Comment: My favorite is Robert Altman's [the Player](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105151/). Not a record, but very well done.

Comment: [This shot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkJ602nb0Vo) from The Protector is around 4 minutes single take. Not quite as long as some of the ones already mentioned, but I think it is worth noting since it is a martial arts movie and the scene involves an incredible number of stunts that all had to be performed correctly to get in a single shot.

Comment: It's not going to win any length awards, but Alton Brown's Good Eats shows regularly have long sequences.

Comment: Hitchcock's "Rope" was filmed without a visible cut - but I guess you are looking for "real" single takes

Comment: Yes, but it is good of you to note Rope here.

Comment: Hitchcock's 80-minute movie "Rope" was all supposed to be a single take, but it was actually ten 8-minute clips cut together so you didn't notice.

Comment: @JoshDM I think my late answer may get lost in the shuffle here, so I respectfully ask you scroll down to read it. *Hopefully this not bad etiquette to request such a thing.*

Comment: @MeatTrademark - not needed for me; unlike some , I review new answers constsntly.

Comment: Just a comment, here's a [Mental Floss article that has a pretty decent list](http://mentalfloss.com/article/56605/13-incredible-unbroken-takes-movies). Forgot about Hard Boiled, that's a great movie.

Comment: **Cannon Fodder** from the [Memories](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113799/) anthology is an interesting example. It's just 22 minutes long and it's actually short animated movie, but it was created in such way that it appears like a single long take and it's worth mentioning because of that.

Comment: I recall that Gus Van Sant's Elephant consists of many long steadycam shots, but I can't find any real data right now. Here's [an example](http://www.steadishots.org/shots_detail.cfm?shotID=67).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess the key here is using the word **film** in your title.

With film you are limited to the length in a canister and no amount of creativity can change that. With digital video this constraint goes out the window. So for *film*, it looks like Snake Eyes wins at just over 13 minutes. For *digital video*, [Agadam](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2574426/) looks to be a clear winner, endorsed by the [Guinness Book of World Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/2000/longest-film-shot-on-a-single-camera) at 2 hr 3 min 30 sec, beating out [7333 Seconds of Johanna](http://www.imdb.com/news/ni44733018/) by 27 seconds.

**EDIT** If @NapoleonWilson is correct, and DePalma used cuts, then [The Player – Opening Shot: 8 minutes, 5 seconds](http://blogs.amctv.com/movie-blog/2007/09/the-ten-best-tr/) might be the winner, and I hope it is, because it talks about other opening shots *during* the shot.

All these directors owe a debt of gratitude to Hitchcock for trying it in the first place. [Rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28film%29) was a very difficult and singular goal to strive for and he did a remarkable job given the technological and financial hurdles he had to overcome.

Comment: Yet the scene in Snake Eyes was composed of smaller ~5 min takes with hidden cuts and thus similar to *Rope*, as explained in [this answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/16609/49). It wasn't an actual 13 min take and is thus unlikely to win anything in the context of this question.

Comment: I was not restricting to film as in the media used, just the context of the product.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Thank you for clarifying that. Back to drawing board...

Comment: But, wouldn't Agadam be the longest?

Comment: Agadam is the single longest take, but it was not on **film.** It was **digital video.** I am trying to define the longest FILM **and** DIGITAL VIDEO shots. Your original question was a little vague as to the medium you were asking about because you mentioned **film** in the title. Film cannot do shots longer than an average of about ten to twelve minutes. Digital Video can shoot a couple hours at an HD rate. Agadam is the longest shot for a movie, but it was not shot on film. That is the difference. :)

Comment: I asked it without realizing there was a need to have a distinction.

Comment: Well then, you got a two-for-one answer! :)

Comment: While I don't know of any films where a single take exceeded the length of a standard roll of camera film, I wouldn't say "no creativity can change that".  While I'm unaware of anyone having done so, I would think it would be possible for someone to build a camera which could accommodate larger reels, and (in complete darkness) hot-splice multiple rolls of camera film onto one giant reel.  Alternatively, one could use a camera with a half-silver mirror to focus light onto two film gates (as with three-strip Technicolor) and arrange things so that the mechanisms...

Comment: ...could be operated separately but synchronized together.  Although doing so would be difficult, it might then be possible to swap the magazine which feeds one film gate while the other one keeps shooting.  If after loading a new film one adjusted its mechanism to run in sync with the other, the images on both films would match perfectly in timing, registration, and focus, so one could invisibly cut between the films at any place where they overlapped.

Comment: @supercat That seems **highly** impractical. All that effort just for a longer shot on film? Creative editing and / or CGI works; or shoot on DV and manipulate it in post to look more "film-like."

Comment: @MeatTrademark: The two-strip camera trick would probably be impractical, but many filmmakers have built or commissioned all sorts of custom camera equipment; a magazine which could handle oversized rolls of film would seem a lot less difficult than many other things which filmmakers have actually built.  Ten minutes isn't terribly long, and it's not hard to imagine a filmmaker (before the age of digital) wanting a continuous take of a long scene which included unpredictably-moving elements that would be very hard to match between takes.

Comment: Presumably this record is going to keep getting broken in future, since (a) someone bothered to get the Guinness Book of Records involved, so now it's a competitive thing, (b) you can in principle point a camera at a theatrical stage, write a play with no intermission, and call the result "a movie". Which is what Hitchcock would have done for Rope if not for the technical limitation on length of a shot. Then it's just a matter of how much storage you can attach to the thing, which will certainly improve over time.

Comment: Indeed, as *Snake Eyes* suggests, it's really easy to hide cuts these days, and probably much cheaper than trying to film an incredibly long shot in one go, so unless someone is specifically trying to break the record, there's no pressing reason to do these kinds of shots "for real".

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I forgot to mention at the outset that I wasn't limiting myself to actual "tracking" shots as per the question (shots utilizing a laid-out track) but included all techniques, hand-held, Steadicam™, etc. Since the OP said film, but didn't mean *just* film, I went ahead and assumed they didn't mean strictly "tracking" shots, either. I imagine I was correct in this assumption, but now I'm getting curious as to the longest FILM TRACKING shot...

Answer (score 20):

There have been movies where the *entire* movie is a single take.

The best I can find based on quick research are [Russian Ark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Ark) at 96 minutes, and [Timecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timecode_%28film%29) at 97 minutes. Timecode is actually a quad-split screen film (four different videos running in four different quadrants of the screen), each of which is a single take shot, running for the entire movie. I included Russian Ark if you wanted something that has a more direct narrative and doesn't change focus to a different story in a different part of the frame by upping the audio track for that frame.

Update: Had I bothered to look a little further down in my Google search, there is evidently a new king for longest single take film. It's a Swedish film called [7333 Seconds of Johanna](http://www.imdb.com/news/ni44733018/). The film is 2 hours, 3 minutes, and 3 seconds long, and was filmed with Guinness World Record officials present the entire time.

Comment: If you had looked a little more, you would have found Agadam - an Indian Tamil Horror film, running time of 2 hours, 3 minutes and 30 seconds, beating _Johanna_ by 27 seconds and registered in Guinness Book of World Records as well.

Answer (score 5):

2015 saw the release of [Victoria](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4226388/), in which **the entire 2 hours and 18 minutes of action takes place in one uncut take**.

Answer (score 3):

- Scorcese's [Copacabana tracking shot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBMKyNJvNV8) in "Goodfellas" needs mentioning.
- This [ten-best tracking shots list from AMC](http://blogs.amctv.com/movie-blog/2007/09/the-ten-best-tr/) lists the opening of "Snake Eyes" as being 13 mins.

Comment: The opening scene of *Snake Eyes* wasn't a single take, though, as explained in [this answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/16609/49).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know "The longest shot" in all of the movies but I remember this movie  [Children Of Men](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0206634/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt) directed by [Alfonso Cuarón](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0190859/?ref_=tt_ov_dr) which has few long shots,

> The length of the long takes: Long take in the car when Julian is shot - 3:58, Long take of the birth - 3:11, Long take of the siege - 6:18.

And  [Quentin Tarantino](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000233/?ref_=nmbio_bio_nm) has a way of filming long shots.

> His films will often include one long, unbroken take where a character is followed around somewhere.

Comment: The ones in Children of Men where edited digitally.

Answer (score 2):

It's not longer than the movies listed above, but the TV show Mad About You had a single take, commercial-free, 20-minute long episode called the "The Conversation".  I haven't seen it since it was aired, though, so I don't remember if the camera was fixed or not.

Comment: Camera did not need to be fixed, as long as it was a continuous take.

Answer (score 2):

There was an episode on the **Third Watch** TV show, that, as far as i can tell, was made entirely on a single shot. That is, about 43 minutes.

In fact, I usually never watched the show, but I started wathcing that one episode, and the fact that the first minutes had a single shot caught my eye, I kept looking it, and the whole episode was one single shot! Single camera, tracking among all the characters.

The episode was "**A call for help**"

Or at least it had VERY good editing, because you never notice if they change something.

update:

I've found out that it indeed was made on long shots, in ten minute loops without cuts.
I guess each loop was sepparated by commercials on TV.

more info here:
http://thirdwatch.wikia.com/wiki/A_Call_For_Help

nonetheless, it was a nice episode, you don't usually see more than a couple minutes of single takes/shots in either TV or Movies.

Answer (score 1):

There's a horror movie called Silent House, I think there's two or three cuts in it but they are all pretty cleverly hidden, besides that the movie is a continuous shot, probably about 30-40 minutes at a time.