# Is Russell Crowe in the opening scene of Beverly Hills Cop?

Tags: character, beverly-hills-cop

Just after [*Beverly Hills Cop*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086960/) starts it shows some parts of Detroit.

About 1:45 in the movie appear 3 people looking at the street and it looks like one of them (the left one) is Russell Crowe.

[image]

I tried to search on the internet. IMDB doesn't have him in the full list of actors. [Some person on another site](http://www.answers.com/mt/beverly-hills-cop) claims it is him indeed.

Does someone have another source to confirm (or negate) that this is him?

Comment: Doesn't look anything like him IMHO.

Comment: My wife asked it to me. At that moment I was persuaded to believe it could be. But since someone as him on Twitter (se answer) she was not the first to think it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Russell Crowe** [**tweeted**](https://twitter.com/russellcrowe/status/63367453908025346) an answer to this three years ago:

> Ha ha, I don't think I could grow a beard when the first Bev hills cop was being made

*(the movie was released in [1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beverly_Hills_Cop), Russell Crowe was born in [1964](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell_Crowe))*

Comment: agreed -- he was 20 in 1984 (when BHC came out). He wasn't on the Hollywood radar for another 8 to 10 years.

Comment: And even more than that he was living on the other side of the world back then.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - regarding your edit, I prefer to let the quote stand on it's own. People should draw their own conclusions. I think the quote is short enough to not need a "summary".

Comment: @Dan agreed he was not on radar at that time. But about a 20/yo guy with so much beard I had a 18/yo workmate that had more beard than Wolverine. :D

Comment: @Oliver_C I agree it's quite obvious, yet I don't agree so much with the general policy of just giving some links or quotes (however valuable) without any kind of summary to answer the actual question (this might keep [some of your answers](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/16609/49) from being accepted, no matter how valuable they are ;-)). I'm not here to draw conclusions, I'm here to get answers...

Comment: @Oliver_C ...But to each his own, it was already upvotable before my edit and I'm not gonna readd it (though I might suggest to at least add a little *"negative"* between *"an"* and *"answer"* to make it more complete, but nevermind).

Comment: Here is a picture of [Russell Crowe](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc0ODU4OTU0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjQ1NjU0NA@@._V1_SX640_SY720_.jpg) around that time ... you can tell the guy in the picture above looks *much* older than Russell.

Comment: I want to give this answer a +1, but the use of the word "twittered" instead of "tweeted" is putting me off :P

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - The problem is that a summary bears the possibility of misinterpretation, especially when there is no clear cut answer. A quote gives you what was actually said. - I agree that for _longer_ answers a summary or emphasizing certain sentences (e.g. by making them bold) is a good idea. - I prefer to present (hopefully relevant) information. What the readers take from it is up to them. I don't want to force feed them _my_ interpretation.

Comment: @Oliver_C Hmm, also true.

Answer (score -1):

Crowe has very distinctive facial moles.  This fellow, although he bears a resemblance, does not have those moles.  Also, in the 80s Crowe was very very thin.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to the Movies and TV Stack Exchange! This answer lacks the detail and references we expect in any answers on this site. For more information on how best to answer questions, please take a Tour of the site - found under the Help menu at the top of the page.

Comment: Can you provide screen-shots for your claims?

Answer (score -1):

It's not,the man on the left & woman were just 2 ppl that I saw every day drinking on the streets & who knows what else.The guy on the right was actually 17 here.

Comment: You're saying you worked on the set?